# How to speed up magento search for product over more than one lakhs products?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am working on a magento site having more than 100,000 products. Searching for a product in the search column takes more than 10 seconds.

Is there any way to speed this up to within, say, 5 seconds.

Comment: You may can find some extensions to do this. You can try some techniques to speed up magento website. http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Comment: for those wondering, 1 lakh products = 100000 products

Answer (score 2):

Magento uses EAV hence the queries are quite comprehensive, you can reduce the time consumed by search functionality by fine-tuning your search settings, mysql fine-tuning, indexing techniques and finally you can also override the search functionality and re factor it your own optimized search functionality.

Fine-tuning Search Settings :

Navigate to System » Catalog » Catalog Search » Search 
Set search type to **Fulltext**, Fulltext is suppose to be most efficient of the three                                   options. For fulltext searching Magento uses separate index maintained in MyISAM engine as InnoDB engine does not support fulltext indexes. Once you have enabled fulltext searching you should ensure that “Catalog Search Index” index is up to date. This can be done from System» Index Management and clicking on “Reindex Data” against “Catalog Search Index”.

Also it is a good idea to cleanse the search queries (eg. Garden Furniture to Garden, if Furniture is a redundant term for your website i.e if you are selling only Furniture and all your product are furniture and the only term that matters is "Garden") using the Catalog Search Terms and redirection options available.

Mysql fine-tuning :

Just having high specs database server might not be usable out of the box, you may require to tweak some settings to get most out of the server's capabilities.

http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-performance-optimize-mysql/

Indexing Techniques :

You can use Sphinx indexer it is a very scalable search server and there are various plugins that help you integrate this in magento. This I think can be very useful and may have a big impact.

Overriding Search Functionality :

The best way however would be to override the search functionality and rewrite the model classes and use Fulltext search which comes along mySQL.

Answer (score 1):

you could use sphinx search server to speed this up.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29 for more information and https://github.com/fheyer/sphinxsearch for an easy-to-install magento extension.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.7.2 by default has a compilation tool built into it. When you first configure Magento, the compiler is disabled and your files have not been compiled. The compilation tool allows you to compile all the files in the Magento 1.7.2 installation to create a single include path. This can increase performance and in initial tests done by the Magento Development team it can improve performance between 25%-50%. Compiling the Magento 1.7.2 installation files is done through the Magento Admin Panel.
Detail on **[here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/201-optimizing-magento/compiling-magento-to-improve-performance)**

Based on my point of view, EAV model style can cause performance problem. Magento use EAV attribute in build in database.

Comment: Looking for speedup search result form database, not for website pefomance !